# Creating shapes inside (square) matrix

Tags: matrices, tikz-pgf

I am trying to type the pictures below in latex but I didn't get it for weeks. I will be VERY glad if I can get help.

[image: image 1: matrix with triangles, rectangle and square shapes]

Please note that for the first image

1. each shape is coloured in gray
2. each shape is labelled such as a1, a2, a3, y etc
3. beside variable y, we have two zeros (left and right) not letter 0 nor circle

[image: Image 2: matrix with anvil shape]

Image 2 has one shape which looks like two anvils join together, then partition with dotted lines.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
A = \left[
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
baseline,
triangle/.style={%
    draw,
    fill=gray!50,
    minimum width=1.4142cm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    isosceles triangle, 
    isosceles triangle apex angle=90,
    shape border uses incircle,
    shape border rotate=#1},
rect/.style={%
        draw, fill=gray!50}
]
\matrix (A) [matrix, row sep=1mm, column sep=2mm] {
\node[triangle=45, anchor=north] (a11) {$a_1$}; &
\node[rect, minimum height=1cm, anchor=north] (a12) {$y_1$}; &
\node[triangle=135, anchor=north] (a13) {$a_2$}; \\
\node[] {$o$}; &
\node[rect, minimum height=1cm] (a22) {$y_1$}; &
\node[] {$o$};\\
\node[triangle=-45, anchor=south] (a31) {$a_3$}; &
\node[rect, minimum height=1cm, anchor=south] (a32) {$y_2$}; &
\node[triangle=-135, anchor=south] (a33) {$a_4$}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\right] \\
A = \left[
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
baseline,
triangle/.style={%
%    fill=gray!50,
    minimum width=1.4142cm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    isosceles triangle, 
    isosceles triangle apex angle=90,
    shape border uses incircle,
    shape border rotate=#1},
rect/.style={%
%    fill=gray!50
    }
]
\matrix (A) [matrix, row sep=0pt, column sep=0pt] {
\node[triangle=45, anchor=north] (a11) {$a_1$}; &
\node[rect, minimum height=1cm, anchor=north] (a12) {$y_1$}; &
\node[triangle=135, anchor=north] (a13) {$a_2$}; \\
\node[] {$o$}; &
\node[rect, minimum height=1cm] (a22) {$y_1$}; &
\node[] {$o$};\\
\node[triangle=-45, anchor=south] (a31) {$a_3$}; &
\node[rect, minimum height=1cm, anchor=south] (a32) {$y_2$}; &
\node[triangle=-135, anchor=south] (a33) {$a_4$}; \\
};
\draw (a11.left corner)--(a13.right corner)--(a22.north east)--(a22.south east)--(a33.left corner)--(a31.right corner)--(a22.south west)--(a22.north west)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (a11.left corner|-a22.north)--(a13.right corner|-a22.north);
\draw[dashed] (a11.left corner|-a22.south)--(a13.right corner|-a22.south);
\draw[dashed] (A.north-|a22.west)--(A.south-|a22.west);
\draw[dashed] (A.south-|a22.east)--(A.north-|a22.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Please, is there a way to join all the shapes form form an anvil (like the one in second picture)?

Comment: @dupsy is setting the matrix with `row sep=0pt, column sep=0pt` enough? or do you need to delete all "inner lines"?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the inner lines after setting row sep=0pt, column sep=0pt.

Comment: @dupsy Look at updated answer.